# Drupal Forum Topic Locked

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, forum

Morning all,

just setting up a Drupal 6 install with the Forum Core Module and Advanced Forum and am coming across a problem where all topics I post are locked as soon as they are posted.

The topics have comments Read/Write selected. I've set permissions so all users except anonymous can post topics.

Done some looking around with no luck or solutions

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue between Advanced Forum and Comment Block which was preventing the rest of the forum layout to load correctly and forcing topics to be locked. Disabling the module let everything drop in to place.